# Edwards: Separation of $\xi(s)$ into real and imaginary parts

Tags: riemann-zeta

[On page 119](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/%7Eywu/Riemann.pdf) Edwards rewrites the $\xi(s)$ function as

$$
\begin{align*}
\xi\left (\frac{1}{2} + it \right ) &= \frac{s}{2}\Pi\left ( \frac{s}{2} - 1 \right )\cdot \pi^{-s/2}\cdot (s - 1) \cdot \zeta(s)\\\\
\\\\
&= e^{\ln \Pi[(s/2) - 1]}\cdot \pi^{-s/2} \cdot \frac{s(s-1)}{2}\cdot \zeta(s)\\\\
\\\\
&= \left [ e^{Re \ln \Pi[(s/2)-1]} \cdot \pi^{-1/4}\cdot \frac{-t^2 - \frac{1}{4}}{2} \right ]\\\\
\\\\
&\times \left [ e^{i Im \ln  \Pi[(s/2) - 1]} \cdot \pi^{-it/2} \cdot \zeta \left ( \frac{1}{2} + it \right )\right ]
\end{align*}
$$

(where $s = 1/2 + it$)

Can you explain how he obtains the expressions inside the brackets?

He seems to separate the real and imaginary parts but then he has a product not addition.

Comment: For example for $s=\frac{1}{2}+i t$ one has $\pi^{-s/2}=\pi^{-1/4} \cdot \pi^{-i t/2}$.

Comment: @StevenClark Ok, thanks. But I could not figure out how the other terms are transformed. I multiplied the `e` terms but I don't get the initial `e` term outside the brackets. Why $\zeta$ is in the second bracket? Is there a name of what he is doing here so that I can look it up further?